# Calling with 'overrides' in Ext JS4

Tags: javascript, extjs4

What is a meaning of call with 'overrides', like this:

```
Ext.form.HtmlEditor.overrides.setReadOnly.call(this, readOnly);
```

This is used from:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.HtmlEditor, {
    setReadOnly: function (readOnly) {
        // some code...
        Ext.form.HtmlEditor.overrides.setReadOnly.call(this, readOnly);
    }
```

Why CallParent can not be used here and what is a meaning of 'overrides', I didn't find that property in Sencha documentation ? I didn't define 'overrides' nowhere.

Comment: What's the `Spx` namespace? If you use `Ext.override` you can use `callParent`

Comment: I've fixed in the code... Ext.override is what I meant :) It's ok with call parent, but I have a code like this and don't know what this 'overrides' mean.

Comment: What version of ExtJS do you use? I tried 4.0.7 and 4.1 and neither creates `overrides` property on overriden class.

Comment: I use 4.1 - and the script works this way, that is why this confuses me.

Comment: Weird. My test proved that both `callParent` and `callOverriden` are working, and there is no `overrides` defined. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/b2cFT/5/